# BigQuery standard SQL query returns a wrong answer

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This query:

```
SELECT x 
FROM dataset.table_a 
WHERE x NOT IN (SELECT x FROM dataset.table_b)
```

returns zero records even though:

- Field `x` in `table_a` contains 1,326,932 distinct string values
- Field `x` in `table_b` contains 18,885 distinct string values

I do not understand why. Moreover, in BigQuery legacy SQL, this query returns the right answer.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data? Is it padded? If you change NOT IN to IN what do you get for a result?

Comment: The migration guide has now been updated to [document the difference between legacy and standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#not_in_conditions_and_null).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that I know the answer--it's due to the incorrect handling of `NULL` in relation to `NOT IN` when using legacy SQL, whereas the behavior with standard SQL agrees with the SQL standard. There is a [documentation bug open for this to add it to the migration guide](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905917) but it hasn't been resolved yet.

The documentation for IN (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#in-operators) states:

> IN with a NULL in the IN-list can only return TRUE or NULL, never FALSE

You can achieve the desired behavior with this query, using `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT x
FROM dataset.table_a AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM dataset.table_b
  WHERE t.x = x
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To my mind, it seems that this rule:

"IN with a NULL in the IN-list can only return TRUE or NULL, never FALSE"

is logically wrong, isn't it ? For instance, 'aa' IN ['bb', NULL] should logically return FALSE ?

Comment: It's equivalent to 'aa' = 'bb' OR 'aa' = NULL, which results in NULL. Try this: `SELECT 'aa' = 'bb' OR 'aa' = (SELECT CAST(NULL AS STRING))`.

Answer (score 3):

To minimize changes in your originalquery you can just add `WHERE NOT x IS NULL` as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT x 
FROM `dataset.table_a` 
WHERE x NOT IN (SELECT x FROM `dataset.table_b` WHERE NOT x IS NULL)
```

Also, I recommend adding DISTINCT as below to optimize it a little

```
#standardSQL
SELECT x 
FROM `dataset.table_a` 
WHERE x NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT x FROM `dataset.table_b` WHERE NOT x IS NULL)
```